# Set shadow on non ortho triangle

Tags: css, svg, styles, frontend

As you can see in the example and if you are familiar with shadowing triangle technique it applies only to ortho triangles.

Anybody familiar with shadowing isosceles or any triangle in general?

It doesn't have to be the same approach even svg is acceptable.
No raster.

Appreciate your kind help.

```css
.ortho{
  top: 400px;
  left:-300px;
  transform: rotate(135deg)
}

.isosceles{
  top: 40px;
  left:40px;
}


.triangle{
  position: relative;
}

.triangle:after{
  
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  content: "\0020";
  border: 40px solid;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: transparent transparent #bada55 #bada55;
  
}


.isosceles:after{
  
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 40px 68px 40px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #dadada transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle ortho"></div>
<div class="triangle isosceles"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use a second pseudo and blur it:

```css
/* added */

.triangle:before {
  content: '';
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -2px;
  top: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\0020";
  border: 43px solid;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000 #000;
}
.isosceles:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  left: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 41px 70px 41px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
}
/* end added */

.ortho {
  top: 400px;
  left: -300px;
  transform: rotate(135deg)
}
.isosceles {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}
.triangle {
  position: relative;
}
.triangle:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\0020";
  border: 40px solid;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: transparent transparent #bada55 #bada55;
}
.isosceles:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 40px 68px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #dadada transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle ortho"></div>
<div class="triangle isosceles"></div>
```

Comment: Great solution 10x. You may add `-webkit-blur` so that other users may see your helpful answer on webkit browser. It didn't work on mine.

Comment: @kidwon did it so webkit user can test demo too :)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using html5

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = 300; // Triangle Width
  var ht = 360; // Triangle ht
  var pd = 95;
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(pd + width / 2, pd);
  c.lineTo(pd + width, ht + pd);
  c.lineTo(pd, ht + pd);
  c.closePath();
  c.shadowBlur = 100;
  c.shadowColor = "lime";
  c.fillStyle = "#444488";
  c.fill();
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(pd + width / 2, ht + pd);
  c.lineTo(pd + width, pd);
  c.lineTo(pd, pd);
  c.closePath();
  c.shadowBlur = 100;
  c.shadowColor = "yellow";
  c.fillStyle = "#222244";
  c.fill();
};
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 22px solid fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<canvas align-="center" border="yellow" id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">Browser not suitable for HTML5.</canvas>
```

See: [isoceles triangle with glow](http://wisephoenix.org/html5/Backlit.htm)

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”